# Проблема с require

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется у меня 2 файла: BinaryTree.js и index.js. Собственно привожу код из файлов:

BinaryTree.js:

```
class Node{
    constructor(data){
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree {
    constructor() {
        this.comparator = null;
    }

    insertNode(node, newNode){
        if(node.data === newNode.data){
            throw new Error('This tree already contains ' + node.data);
        }
        if(newNode.data < node.data){
            if(node.left === null){
                node.left = newNode
            }else{
                this.insertNode(node.left, newNode)
            }
        }else{
            if(node.right === null){
                node.right = newNode;
            }else{
                this.insertNode(node.right,newNode);
            }
        }
    }

    insert(str){
        let newNode = new Node(str);
        if(this.comparator === null){
            this.comparator = newNode;
        }else{
            this.insertNode(this.comparator, newNode);
        }
    }

    remove(str){
        this.search(this.comparator, str);
        this.comparator = this.removeNode(this.comparator, str);
    }

    removeNode(node, key){
        if(node === null){
            return null;
        }else if(key < node.data){
            node.left = this.removeNode(node.left, key);
            return node;
        }else if(key > node.data){
            node.right = this.removeNode(node.right, key);
            return node;
        }else{
            if(node.left === null && node.right === null){
                node = null;
                return node;
            }
            if(node.left === null){
                node = node.right;
                return node;
            }else if(node.right === null){
                node = node.left;
                return node;
            }

            let aux = this.findMinNode(node.right);
            node.data = aux.data;
            node.right = this.removeNode(node.right, aux.data);
            return node;
        }
    }

    search(node, str){
        if(node === null){
            throw new Error('This tree does not contain ' + str);
        }else if(str < node.data){
            return this.search(node.left, str);
        }else if(str > node.data){
            return this.search(node.right, str);
        }else{
            return node;
        }
    }

    findMinNode(node) {    
        if(node.left === null) 
            return node; 
        else
            return this.findMinNode(node.left);
        }

    toArrayInternal(node, array){
        if(node !== null){
            this.toArrayInternal(node.left, array);
            array.push(node.data);            
            this.toArrayInternal(node.right, array);
        }

    }

    toArray(){
        let fullArray = [];
        this.toArrayInternal(this.getRootNode(), fullArray);
        return fullArray;        
    }

    getRootNode(){
        return this.comparator;
    }

    heightInternal(node){
        if (!node){
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + Math.max(this.heightInternal(node.left), 
    this.heightInternal(node.right));
    }

    height(){        
        return this.heightInternal(this.getRootNode());                
    }
}

module.exports = new BinaryTree();
```

index.js:

```
let tree = require ('./BinaryTree.js');

tree.insert('b');
tree.insert('a');
tree.insert('c');

console.log(tree.height());// 2
console.log(tree.toArray());// ['a','b','c']

tree.remove('b');
tree.insert('b');

console.log(tree.height());// 3
console.log(tree.toArray());// ['a','b','c']

tree.insert('z');

console.log(tree.height());// 3
console.log(tree.toArray());// ['a','b','c','z']

tree.insert('y');
tree.insert('x');

console.log(tree.height());// 4
console.log(tree.toArray());// ['a','b','c','x','y','z']

try{
    tree.insert('x');
} catch({message}){
    console.log(message)// This tree already contains 'x'
}

try{
    tree.remove('x');
    tree.remove('x');
} catch({message}){
    console.log(message)// This tree does not contain 'x'
}

tree = require ('./BinaryTree.js');

tree.insert('a');
tree.insert('b');
tree.insert('c');
tree.insert('d');
tree.insert('e');

console.log(tree.height());// 5
console.log(tree.toArray());// ['a','b','c','d','e']

tree.remove('b');
tree.remove('a');
tree.remove('c');
tree.remove('d');
tree.remove('e');

console.log(tree.height());// 0
console.log(tree.toArray());// []
```

Собственно к сути вопроса. Почему при запуске index.js:
1) после try{}catch{} скрипт ложится с ошибкой
2) при повторном создании класса BinaryTree, comparator не равен null

P.S. я бы мог подумать, что накосячил где-то, но если весь код перенести из index в BinaryTree, то работает всё без нареканий. Заранее благодарю за ответы/советы.

P.P.S. не уверен что смогу оставлять комментарии =(

Comment: А текст ошибки-то где? И вообще говоря, приведенный index.js должен падать на первой же строчке, с сообщением "BinaryTree is not defined"

Comment: как и предыдущего оратора меня также смущает вопрос как вы используете класс `BinaryTree` в `index.js`, если его реализация описана в другом файле + вы экспортите инстанс, а не сам класс? и конечно же если перенести из файла `index.js` в другой файл - будет все работать

Comment: @ overthesanity @ Yaant  Упс, исправил 1ую строчку. + добавил скрин ошибки

Answer (score 0):

При первом вызове `require` выполняет указанный модуль и кладет результат (в данном случае созданный экземпляр класса `BinaryTree`) в кэш. При повторном вызове оно просто берет результат (тот же самый объект) из кэша. Подробнее см. в [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching).

Comment: Благодарю! Всё решил